# Foundation -[NSConcreteMapTable assign:key:value:isNew:] Crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at

Tags: ios, ios7, crash-reports, crashlytics

I have a crash that happens only in IOS 7, I cannot reproduce it but it happens a lot. Does some one have an answer or at least have any idea where the problem can be.
I've allready removed all the warnings regarding ios7 and the crash still occurs.
Log is attached.

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3b43c626 objc_msgSend + 5
1  Foundation                     0x315a9681 -[NSConcreteMapTable assign:key:value:isNew:] + 68
2  Foundation                     0x315a95fb -[NSConcreteMapTable setObject:forKey:] + 82
3  Foundation                     0x315ecaf7 -[NSISEngine setRowWithHead:body:] + 30
4  Foundation                     0x315ef5d1 -[NSISEngine pivotToMakeBodyVar:newHeadOfRowWithHead:andDropRow:] + 388
5  Foundation                     0x315ed325 -[NSISEngine minimizeConstantInObjectiveRowWithHead:] + 236
6  Foundation                     0x315efd9f -[NSISEngine tryUsingArtificialVariableToAddConstraintWithMarker:rowBody:usingInfeasibilityHandlingBehavior:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 226
7  Foundation                     0x315eb5fd -[NSISEngine tryToAddConstraintWithMarker:expression:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 692
8  Foundation                     0x315eb23b -[NSLayoutConstraint _addLoweredExpression:toEngine:integralizationAdjustment:lastLoweredConstantWasRounded:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 286
9  Foundation                     0x315e8f6d -[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 232
10 Foundation                     0x315f47ed -[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:] + 28
11 UIKit                          0x33591c55 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 332
12 Foundation                     0x315e8b2b -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 210
13 UIKit                          0x33591ad9 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 336
14 UIKit                          0x3349e20d -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 200
15 UIKit                          0x33591bbb __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 178
16 Foundation                     0x315e8b2b -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 210
17 UIKit                          0x33591ad9 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 336
18 UIKit                          0x3349e20d -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 200
19 UIKit                          0x33591bbb __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 178
20 Foundation                     0x315e8b2b -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 210
21 UIKit                          0x33591ad9 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 336
22 UIKit                          0x3349e20d -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 200
23 UIKit                          0x33591bbb __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 178
24 Foundation                     0x315e8b2b -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 210
25 UIKit                          0x33591ad9 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 336
26 UIKit                          0x3349e20d -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 200
27 UIKit                          0x3349de33 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 82
28 Foundation                     0x315e8b2b -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 210
29 UIKit                          0x3349dcd3 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 298
30 UIKit                          0x334aaa4f -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1414
31 UIKit                          0x334aa4bf -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 30
32 UIKit                          0x3358bdb7 -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:removeFromView:] + 978
33 UIKit                          0x335cbf3f -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 30
34 UIKit                          0x335cbf15 -[UITransitionView transition:toView:] + 104
35 UIKit                          0x335cb03b -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 1106
36 UIKit                          0x335cabdf -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 38
37 UIKit                          0x335caab7 -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 258
38 UIKit                          0x33694dd5 -[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:] + 272
39 UIKit                          0x334d4037 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 90
40 UIKit                          0x334d3fd7 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 30
41 UIKit                          0x33694c8b -[UITabBar _sendAction:withEvent:] + 370
42 UIKit                          0x334d4037 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 90
43 UIKit                          0x334d3fd7 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 30
44 UIKit                          0x334d3fb1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44
45 UIKit                          0x334bf717 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 374
46 UIKit                          0x336949ab -[UITabBar(Static) _buttonUp:] + 118
47 UIKit                          0x334d4037 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 90
48 UIKit                          0x334d3fd7 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 30
49 UIKit                          0x334d3fb1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44
50 UIKit                          0x334bf717 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 374
51 UIKit                          0x334d3a2f -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 590
52 UIKit                          0x334d3701 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 528
53 UIKit                          0x334ce6cb -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 758
54 UIKit                          0x334a38cd -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 196
55 UIKit                          0x334a1f77 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7102
56 CoreFoundation                 0x30c4d20b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
57 CoreFoundation                 0x30c4c6db __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 206
58 CoreFoundation                 0x30c4aecf __CFRunLoopRun + 622
59 CoreFoundation                 0x30bb5ebf CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
60 CoreFoundation                 0x30bb5ca3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
61 GraphicsServices               0x35abb663 GSEventRunModal + 138
62 UIKit                          0x3350214d UIApplicationMain + 1136
```

Comment: Same here, sometimes it crashes on Foundation or UIKit

Comment: Do you know what causes this crash?

Comment: No, I hope this post could collect answer

Comment: I get the same issue. The strange thing is it only occurs in 3.5inch devices (ip4, ip4S), os7.x. works fine on ip5 I try many way but still can not fix the bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for who ever responded.
I solved it by removing the keyboard (resignFirstResponder) before poping the view controller.

In that screen I had 2 textfields that one of them was connected to the keyboard(inpuAccessoryView)and the other just activated the first one (I was developing a chat), when poping the view controller something probably went wrong.

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar crash, except it happened when I did `removeFromSuperview` on a UIView that was created while inside a network callback. `[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:]` was where it started to go wrong after removeFromSuperview

eg. inside `handleReadStreamEvent`

```
if (!CFReadStreamSetClient( inputStream, kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable | kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred | kCFStreamEventEndEncountered | kCFStreamEventOpenCompleted
                           , handleReadStreamEvent, &context ) )
```

It seems any view that was created while inside this callback, crashed when it was removed from the superview - most of the time.

I ended up using this whenever I was making any UIView changes when inside the callback.

```
- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay;
```

The same happened when inside a looptimer callback

```
CFRunLoopAddTimer( CFRunLoopGetMain(), timeoutTimer, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the same issue. The strange thing is it only occurs in 3.5inch devices (ip4, ip4S), os7.x. works fine on ip5.

UPDATE: our team found the root cause. It's because we use this animation in code.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.5f initialSpringVelocity:0.3f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
                self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(sx,sy);
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                self.hidden = !visible;
            }];
```

to fix the bug, we avoid to run the animation if iOS <8.0

```
 if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.5f initialSpringVelocity:0.3f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(sx,sy);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            if (finished) {
                self.hidden = !visible;
            }
        }];
    } else {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(sx,sy);
        self.hidden = !visible;
    }
```

Hope this help!